# How to get Pyglet Working for Python 3?

Tags: python, pyglet

I am excited to use Pyglet because of all its features, however I am having problems installing the latest development build of Pyglet on Python 3. I am aware people have already asked this question but none of the responses helped me at all.

UPDATE:
What I mean is that I am unable to get Pyglet to install for Python 3, whenever I import Pyglet it showss an error message with some Python 2 code.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "problems": can't import pyglet, can't run any/some tests etc

Answer (score 4):

Install using the below command:

```
pip3 install pyglet
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of installing pyglet you can also put a copy of pyglet in the project folder and import it from there. This approach makes it also easy to use different versions of pyglet for your projects.

To make pyglet running on python 3 you need to convert the latest version of pyglet using [2to3](https://wiki.python.org/moin/2to3). Without that conversion it will not run on python 3. With previous versions of pyglet you will have difficulties when trying to convert it so make sure to use 1.2 (which is currently at alpha state but quite stable).

Comment: pyglet versions can be downloaded from here : https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/downloads/

Answer (score 3):

I used:

```
    pip3 install pyglet
```

and it works perfectly. Make sure that when you run python from the terminal you use

```
    python3
```

and not

```
    python
```

because that messed it up for me at first.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to pip install from the rep, e.g. using

```
pip install -e hg+https://pyglet.googlecode.com/hg/@2813:0aa8bfe3313a#egg=pyglet
```

this is because the current version of pyglet in pip is not compatible with python 3 yet.

Comment: It still did not install Pyglet on Python 3.

Comment: @user2438758, look, we are trying to help you, specially Matthew, and it seems you are not making any effort to be helped. Please, specify your problem concretely, giving us *exactly* what were the commands you have used to install, and *exactly* what were the results obtained, in each command in your question. Until then, -1.

Comment: If he hasn't got mercurial, he could also install it with `pip install --upgrade http://pyglet.googlecode.com/archive/tip.zip`

Answer (score 0):

I applied the answer of @J. C. Leitão to Ubuntu 14.04.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-git mercurial
sudo pip3 install -e hg+https://pyglet.googlecode.com/hg/@2813:0aa8bfe3313a#egg=pyglet
```

And now I can import pyglet.

(However it seems to not work properly. If I run the [hello world program](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/hello_world.py) the Hello world can not bee seen in the window. I can see just darkness in it.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you want to use it with python3 and you are installing it with pip, which is for python2, pip3 is for python3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing using pip, try typing pip3 install pyglet and it will install for python 3 instead of python 2.
(Any time you want to install for python3, use pip3 instead of pip)

If it is installed correctly, make sure you save the python file in the same folder that you have pyglet installed. If it is not installed and you don't have the path set up, it won't import.

Answer (score -1):

If you have pip installed, then it should be easy,
just use "pip install pyglet".
Else install pip, it makes installing python packages a lot easier.

Comment: pip is NOT for Python3.
Use pip3 for Python3.

Comment: You can get `get-pip.py` from the ppa, run it and I believe you can pip install like `python3.6 -m pip install <package>`