# Plot with sympy in Python 3

Tags: sympy, python-3.4, pyglet

I wanted to plot a the [3D plotting example from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SymPy#Plotting_2):

```
from sympy import symbols, Plot, cos
x,y = symbols('x y')
Plot(cos(x*3)*cos(y*5)-y)
```

As I want to use Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, [I installed pyglets (1.2alpha1) from the mercurial repository of googlecode with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25790754/813946) and sympy (0.7.5) was installed by pip3 too. (Earlier pyglets versions do not work with Python 3.)

But at the last line ipython3 gives an error message:

```
In [3]: Plot(cos(3*x)*cos(5*y)-y)
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/proxy_pyglet.py:35: SymPyDeprecationWarning: 

Plot as an interface to Pyglet has been deprecated since SymPy 0.7.2.
See http://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=2845 for more
info.  This interface will change in future versions of SymPy.  As a
precaution use the plot() function (lowercase), or use
sympy.plotting.pygletplot.PygletPlot to continue using Pyglet.  See
the docstring of this function for details.

  ).warn()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d5373dfc3f15> in <module>()
----> 1 Plot(cos(3*x)*cos(5*y)-y)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/proxy_pyglet.py in Plot(*args, **kwargs)
     35     ).warn()
     36 
---> 37     return PygletPlot(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/pygletplot/__init__.py in PygletPlot(*args, **kwargs)
    137         """
    138 
--> 139         import plot
    140         return plot.PygletPlot(*args, **kwargs)
    141 

ImportError: No module named 'plot'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With matplotlib installed the code below works as expected:

```
from sympy import symbols, cos
from sympy.plotting import plot3d
x, y = symbols('x y')
plot3d(cos(x*3)*cos(y*5)-y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Pyglet plotting module is not well supported any more. I would recommend using the new plotting module, which uses matplotlib. Use `plot` instead of `Plot`.

Comment: plot function plots only expressions with one variables. But I have found the plot3d function, that can do that I wanted. Thanks!